# not getting data when sending Push Notification with Parse Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using `PushService.subscribe(context,channel,NotificationActivity.class)` to subscribe to the channel to get the push notification. I am able to get the push notification but not able to get the additional data in `NotificationActivity`. Here is my code.

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
data.put("action","com.example.myapp.UPDATE_STATUS")
data.put("postTitle",result.get(0).getTitle() );
data.put("description", result.get(0).getDescription());

ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setChannel(tag);
push.setData(data);
push.setMessage("Meassge sent is"+tag);
push.send();

NotificationActivity
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);
ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent()); 
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
JSONObject jsonData1;
jsonData1 = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString( "com.parse.Data" ));
while (itr.hasNext()) {
     String key = (String) itr.next();
         Log.d("NotificationActivity Logs", "..." + key + " => " +                      jsonData1.getString(key));
}
```

In the output (Logcat) I am only getting two keys. `alert` and `push_hash`, but not giving any other key which I set like `title` and `description`.

Comment: I just found the solution. I should not have setMessage(). Whhen using setData, it already has a title field to set the message. So either use setData or setMeassge.

Comment: 3 hours. Thank you for this little but invaluable comment!